# Can't deploy docker and webpack app to Heroku

Tags: docker, heroku, webpack

I am having an issue when I try to deploy to Heroku my webpack/django and react app. I folowed the heroku documentation for building docker images with heroku.yml but when I try git push to heroku, it gives the error:

```
=!= validate step: error converting YAML to JSON: yaml: line 12: did not find expected alphabetic or numeric character

If this persists, please contact us at https://help.heroku.com/.
Verifying deploy...

! [remote rejected] branch-name -> main (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/app.git'
```

In my heroku.yml file I have the inputs for the config taken from my env file, and the docker paths are for the four docker files I have in their respective folders.

Here are my files:

heroku.yml

```
setup:
  addons:
    - plan: heroku-postgresql
      as: DATABASE
  config:
    ESLINT_NO_DEV_ERRORS: true
    POSTGRES_PASSWORD: "w1rog-bht7c618d86ycv3ny2_1(d!gn9p)%b_wbq^s%y_taw!y"
    POSTGRES_USER: sidelab_app
    DJANGO_ADMIN_URL: aa/
    DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE: config.settings.production
    DJANGO_SECRET_KEY: "hm7xavyu3^%8o7qruw8gsv&7xvgdreo%v3%dks8vpq=y9o(ynz"
    DJANGO_ALLOWED_HOSTS: *
    DJANGO_SERVER_EMAIL: "sidelab_app <noreply@mg.sidelab.ie>"
    DJANGO_ACCOUNT_ALLOW_REGISTRATION: true
build:
  docker:
    web: web/Dockerfile
    worker: docker/caddy/Dockerfile
    worker: docker/django/Dockerfile
    worker: docker/node/Dockerfile
    worker: docker/postgres/Dockerfile
```